# A CSS renders badly in Firefox only

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, rendering

I add with JS these 2 buttons on the left of the filter box:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

[image]

Here is the `buttonfile` CSS style:

```
.buttonfile {
  text-indent: 0;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This renders properly on Chrome and Edge but not on Firefox (v115.0.2 latest) where it is rendered this way:

[image]

I tried countless changes to `buttonfile` style with no luck. So I ended up by hiding the buttons with this Firefox specific hack:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {.buttonfile{ display:none; } }
```

What can be done to make the Firefox rendering fine?

---

If it can help, here are styles applied to the filter box:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example to your question?

Comment: The first step is identifying which style specifically is causing the issue. After that, it's just replacing it with a better style.

Comment: Have you used your FF's devtools inspect facility to see exactly who/where is adding the CSS which is causing this?

Comment: In general, nowadays float is not a good way of positioning things (unless you really do want for example text to float round an image or other element).

Comment: Yeah it's most likely `float` style that's causing it. If you can add the minimum reproducible example, I can take another look.

Answer (score 0):

There was a `text-indent:-9999px;` in the parent div style that messed it up all on FireFox, without that it works.